# Recursion which seems to explode

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I am trying to understand the following recursion,

$$Y_{t}=(1.2)Y_{t-1}-(0.4)Y_{t-2}+Z_{t} $$ $t \in \mathbb{Z}$

Where ${Z_{t}}$ are iid $N(0,\sigma^{2}$))

My trouble is that the $1.2$ factor seems to make it blow up as we iterate the recursion, thus giving me difficulty in getting a form for $Y_{t}.$

I do see that we will have a term,

$$\sum_{g=0}^{\infty} (1.1)^{g} Z_{t-g}$$

but I don't know how to account for the rest of the recursion that goes on forever since t includes negative integers as well. Along with accounting for the (1.2) factor which will go to infinity.

Also something that seems interesting is that if we try to calculate the mean of both sides it seems to imply that $\mu=0$

Comment: I know what $N(0,\sigma^2)$ means, but what is $WN$?

Comment: So they are iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$. It'd be about the same length, and more standard terminology, to refer to it that way.

Comment: Did you do any numerical experiments?

Comment: @neal I'm not sure how to do that when I don't know any base values

Comment: Here's a python 3 script that takes in a two-element list `initial` of initial values, e.g. `[1,1]`.  https://gist.github.com/necoleman/20f06056ffcaafb93643ad48cbe2193d

Answer (score 1):

This is not any different from the deterministic case. You have

$$Y_t-1.2 Y_{t-1}+0.4Y_{t-2}=Z_t$$

where $Z_t$ doesn't depend explicitly on $Y_t$. The general homogeneous solution is

$$H_t=c_1 r_1^t + c_2 r_2^t$$

where $r_1,r_2$ are solutions to $\lambda^2-1.2\lambda+0.4=0$, which are easily found. The particular solution is the convolution of $Z_t$ with a particular homogeneous solution $P_t$. I think it will be the one with $P_1=1,P_0=0$, whose coefficients are the solution to

$$\begin{bmatrix} r_1 & r_2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

which is the first column of the inverse of the coefficient matrix, i.e. $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{r_1-r_2} \\ \frac{-1}{r_1-r_2} \end{bmatrix}$. ($r_1$ and $r_2$ are indeed different in this case).

The general solution to the inhomogeneous problem is the sum of a particular solution and the general homogeneous solution. Note that this is generally not bounded in either direction in time, since $0<r_1<1<r_2$.

Comment: @PersonaA The particular solution does look pretty much like that, but I think the relevant convolution kernel (what you called $\lambda_g$) involves *both* exponentials, not just one of them. Unless the left side is $Y_t+bY_{t-1}+cY_{t-2}$ and $b^2-4c=0$, then the situation is a bit different. I'm also not really sure why the blowup creates any particular difficulty.

Comment: I'm just a little confused because it seem you are using method of differential equation? How do you know you can solve it like this?

Comment: @PersonaA The basic method of homogeneous+particular relies only on linearity, it has nothing really to do with differential equations. All that is going on is that the difference of any two inhomogeneous solutions is a homogeneous solution. The convolution thing is a bit more specific, but you can look up Green's functions in difference equations if you like.

Comment: @PersonaA I'm using the concept of the Green's function of a linear recurrence relation. That should be out there online.

Comment: I tried looking at that, it doesn't seem so accessible to me.. I understand most of this, I think there may be a way to understand it without greens.  Is there a reason that in the matrix calculation c1+c2=0 ?

Comment: @PersonaA That's coming from the properties of the Green's function. If you want, you could just try guessing that the particular solution is in the form of a convolution of *some* homogeneous solution with $Z_t$ and solving for the coefficients. This is how you would derive the Green's function from scratch anyway.

Comment: I see, I'm a bit confused because Zt is a random variable so method of undermined coeff doesn't seem to work, should I use MGF? Do youthink you could possibly show a bit more what you mean? I do want to solve the problem with a understanding

Comment: @PersonaA $Z_t$ is totally arbitrary here (the randomness has nothing to do with anything). Essentially you need a method for dealing with general forcing. The Green's function method is the most straightforward way to do this (though there is a version of "variation of parameters" for linear recurrences as well). It's a bit tedious to write it out so I'd really rather not.

Comment: ,, Okay fair enough.

Comment: However I think I must still leave the question open for now as I don't really understand the approach.. will check back with it

Comment: In your method if we solve we get complex roots for the roots

Comment: @PersonaA The method works anyway. For real initial conditions, the imaginary parts will cancel out.